# react: отложеннное задание свойств компоненту

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, компоненты, setstate

Подскажите как разрешить следующую ситуацию:

У меня есть несколько компонент, которые я знаю изначально и формирую из них некоторый список `listData`

у каждой компоненты есть некоторые свойства (в примере свойство `id`), которое я не знаю изначально и которое генерируется уже по ходу работы сайта (в примере в качестве этого функционала выступает функция `generateID`).

мне необходимо как-то передать компоненту это свойство, но как это сделать?

изменить `props` я не могу, поскольку React его делает readonly
а изменить `state` что-то не очень получается :(

Подскажите как корректнее бы это сделать.
В идеале было бы замечательно, если бы внутри компонента я бы к свойствам, которые могу задать в самом начале и которые определяю динамически, получал бы доступ одинаково, а еще лучше - как к единому пулу свойств (как это происходит с `props`)

Например, динамически для `MyElement1` и `MyElement2` мне надо задать свойство `id`, которое уже внутри этих компонент я могу использовать,

Но есть и свойства, которые я задаю сразу (статически) и которые также внутри этих компонент могу использовать (например, свойство `type`)

```
    // задать список элементов
    const listData= [
        <MyElement1 type = "element1" />,
        <MyElement2 />
    ];
```

Вот пример тестового кода

```
import MyElement1 from './MyElement1'
import MyElement2 from './MyElement2'

class MyList extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
       super();

        // задать список элементов
        const listData= [
            <MyElement1 />,
            <MyElement2 />
        ];

        // сформировать список элементов
        this.state = {
            listData:   queryData.map((params, index) => {

                            // сгенерировать уникальный ID
                            const id = generateID();

                            // как-то передать ID компоненту {params}
                            params.props["id"] = id; // НЕЛЬЗЯ поскольку props - readonly
                            params.setState({id: id}); // НЕЛЬЗЯ поскольку нет такой функции (setState)

                            return (
                                        <div key = {index} id = {id}>{params}</div>
                                    );
                        })
        };
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.m_queryComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то вам нужно использовать подход с [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).
Должно получиться, что-то в этом роде:

```
const listData = [
  props => <MyElement1 type="element1" {...props} />,
  props => <MyElement2 {...props} />
];
const generateId = () => random(1, 1000);

const App = () => {
  console.log(111);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Elements</h3>
      <div>
        {listData.map(MyElement => {
          const id = generateId();
          return <MyElement id={id} key={id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k9z26mwxr3

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте следующий варинат:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import MyElement1 from './MyElement1';
import MyElement2 from './MyElement2';

const generateID = () => 'some id';

class MyList extends Component {
  state = {
    element1Id: null,
    element2Id: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // do some stuff
    const element1Id = generateID();
    const element2Id = generateID();
    this.setState({ element1Id, element2Id });
  }

  render() {
    const { element1Id, element2Id } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {element1Id && <MyElement1 />}
        {element2Id && <MyElement2 />}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyList;
```

Comment: видите, вы компоненты в `render()` засунули

а хотелось бы в render отрисовать массив просто, т.е. в `render()` не вписывать руками ничего дополнительно

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение в использовании контекста React,

Создаю контекст и передаю свойство, которое получают все компоненты по дереву, начиная от родителя для которого и применяется контекст

у нужного родителя (я его в абстрактный класс превратил)

```
render()
{
    return (
        <CardContext.Provider value = {this.state.context}>
            {this._base_render()}
        </CardContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

недостаток метода -

1. по первых контекст приходится задать в отдельном .js файле
2. этот контекст приходится тащить по нужным потомкам
3. если я создам несколько наследников от базового класса, то контекст
   у них будет один на всех и меня спасает только одноразовость его
   использования (т.е. изменение контекста меня не волнует... пока)

А вообще ещё советую на redux обратить внимание как на замену контекста.

Comment: Redux под капотом построен на Context API :)